# About a translation invariant operator with inverse Fourier transform.

Tags: fourier-analysis, operator-theory, fourier-transform

Let $T:L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ a operator with $T(u)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g(\xi)\hat{u})$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ nonegative and rotationally invarian function.
Then, Why $T$ is translation invariant operator? ($\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is a inverse Fourier Transform)

Comment: What means rotationally invariant in 1D? Even? is $g:\Bbb R ^n\cdots$?

Comment: Well, again: What *means* rotationally invariant in 1D?